# Español para el gesto de "tongue-in-cheek"

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones

En inglés, la expresión *tongue-in-cheek* ([1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tongue%20in%20cheek), [2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tongue-in-cheek), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek)) se usa para indicar que algo debe entenderse en tono de broma, irónico, o simplemente que no debe tomarse en serio.

Si revisamos los [ejemplos en Linguee](https://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/tongue+in+cheek.html), vemos que no hay una manera establecida de traducir esta expresión. De hecho, los cuatro primeros que me aparecen tienen cada uno una traducción diferente:

- ***tongue-in-cheek*** comment → observación **algo burlona**
- *their acidic and ironic lyrics, their **tongue-in-cheek** universe* → letras ácidas e irónicas, **llenas de humor**
- ***tongue-in-cheek*** humor → humor **irónico**
- *I would tell him, equally **tongue-in-cheek*** → le diría, también **en broma**

Mientras que otros ejemplos directamente omiten la expresión y se quedan tan panchos. Incluso la [entrada de la Wikipedia en español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek) la usa tal cual, sin ofrecer una traducción.

El caso es que el origen de esta expresión, que literalmente significa "con la lengua en la mejilla", viene del gesto de presionar la mejilla desde dentro con la lengua, así:

[image: tongue in cheek]
<sub>Autor: Piers Nye. Licencia Creative Commons [BY-NC](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/). [Enlace al original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/piers_nye/2350197149).</sub>

Mi pregunta es: ¿**existe en español alguna palabra o expresión para referirse a este gesto**?
Y en caso de que no la haya, ¿existe alguna otra expresión, relacionada con gestos, que pueda usarse en el mismo sentido que el *tongue in cheek* inglés?

Comment: Fíjate que nunca había hecho la conexión entre la cara que hace el niño en la foto y el modismo -- y el inglés es mi primer idioma....

Comment: No estoy para nada sorprendido que no exista ninguna traducción para esta expresión. Pasa que no es un tipo de humor muy apreciado ni practicado en el mundo hispanohablante y aún menos en España. En Flandes, tenemos un sentido de humor sarcástico muy parecido al humor Inglés. Pero en España, _**metí muchas veces la pata**_ con este tipo de humor. ¡Vale mejor _**morderse la lengua!**_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encuentro expresiones para el mismo gesto, ni tampoco expresiones que indiquen algo parecido. Te indico las más cercanas que he encontrado:

> **[moflearse](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PVtkqlz)**
>
> 1. prnl. *Sal.* Burlarse de alguien hinchando los mofletes.

Usada solo en Salamanca, pero es lo más parecido que he encontrado.

> **[torcer la boca](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5i6aRwS#BZwK7A1)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. Volver el labio inferior hacia alguno de los carrillos, en ademán o en demostración de disgusto.

No exactamente lo que preguntabas, pero al menos menciona los carrillos.